# First item displayed two times in the Listview Android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Hi I already posted the question before but again same question with details ,
I created a a NavigationDrawer in the app , Its working fine but the problem is that in `FolderActivity`  the first Item as a title displayed two time in navigation drawer, I posted the code below please suggest me solution if any...!

**navigation_drawer_class.java**

```
package com.abc;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.R.*;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.BaseBundle;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class navigation_drawer_class extends Activity
{
private static final int Copy = 0;
int a =0;
public static FrameLayout frameLayout;
TextView mytextview;
public static ListView mDrawerList;
public DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
String Fullname;
protected String[] listArray = {"Home","Queue","Inbox","Create Ticket","Search","Clients","App settings"};
protected static int position;
private static boolean isLaunch = true;
JSONObject post_details_obj,post_obj;

public static String FIRST_NAME="first_name",LAST_NAME="last_name",PROFILE_IMAGE="image_name";
JSONArray staff_data_array;

private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
Operation op=new Operation();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
getActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.crop3);//THIS ONE FOR THE DRAWER LOGO
frameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listArray));


View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.headerview_nav_drawer,null);
TextView headerValue = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.headerview_id);
headerValue.setText("");

new getname().execute();

mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
{
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
int position, long id)
{

position -= mDrawerList.getHeaderViewsCount();//THIS ONE FOR THE FIRST ITEM AS TITLE

openActivity(position);
}

});
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
this,      // host Activity 
mDrawerLayout,     // DrawerLayout object 
R.drawable.ic_launcher,     // nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret 
R.string.open_drawer,       // "open drawer" description for accessibility 
R.string.close_drawer)      // "close drawer" description for accessibility 
{
@Override
public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) 
{
getActionBar().setTitle(listArray[position]);
invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
}

@Override
public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
{
getActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
}

@Override
public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) 
{
super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
}

@Override
public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) 
{
super.onDrawerStateChanged(newState);
}
};
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

if(isLaunch){
isLaunch = false;
openActivity(0);

}
}

protected void openActivity(int position) {

//mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
//setTitle(listArray[position]);
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
navigation_drawer_class.position = position; //Setting currently selected position in this field so that it will be available in our child activities.

switch (position) {
case 0:
startActivity(new Intent(this, Folders.class));

break;

case 1:

Intent i=new Intent(navigation_drawer_class.this,G.class);

startActivity(i);    
break;

case 2:
Intent inbox=new Intent(navigation_drawer_class.this,E.class);
startActivity(inbox);    
break;

case 3:
startActivity(new Intent(this, S.class));
break;

case 4:
startActivity(new Intent(this, A.class));
break;

case 5:
startActivity(new Intent(this, P.class));
break;

case 6:
startActivity(new Intent(this, V.class));
break;

default:


break;
}   
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
//  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
// The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
// ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) 
{
return true;
}
switch (item.getItemId())
{
default:
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{

//boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
//menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/* We can override onBackPressed method to toggle navigation drawer*/
@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{
if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList))
{
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}
else 
{
mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
}
}


private class getname extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONArray>
{
Dialog dialog;
@Override
public void onPreExecute() 
{
dialog = new Dialog(navigation_drawer_class.this,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.progressbar);
dialog.show();
}

@Override
protected JSONArray doInBackground(Void... params) 
{

String STAFF_URL=op.getUrl(getApplicationContext(),"staff","get_staff_details","");
staff_data_array = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(STAFF_URL+"&vis_encode=json",navigation_drawer_class.this);
return staff_data_array;

}
@Override
public void onPostExecute(JSONArray staff_data_array) 
{   
super.onPostExecute(staff_data_array);
String staff_data_result =staff_data_array.toString();

try {
post_obj = staff_data_array.getJSONObject(0);
String fname=post_obj.getString(FIRST_NAME);
String lname=post_obj.getString(LAST_NAME);
String image=post_obj.getString(PROFILE_IMAGE);

String fullname =fname;

if(fullname=="")
{
fullname="Admin";
}

Fullname="Welcome "+fullname;

View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.headerview_nav_drawer,null);
TextView headerValue = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.headerview_id);
headerValue.setText(Fullname);

headerValue.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.default_img,0,0,0);
mDrawerList.addHeaderView(headerValue, null, false);



} catch (JSONException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}

dialog.dismiss();
}
}
}
```

**Folders.java**

```
package com.abc;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.R.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Folders extends navigation_drawer_class {

static final String NEW="A", OVERDUE ="B", ASSIGNED="C", TRASH="D", SPAM="E",NAME="name",COUNT="count";

ListView folders_list;
String[] folders;
String[] filter_id ={"2","3","4","5","6"};
List<String> folder_count; 
JSONArray quick_view_array;
JSONObject quick_view_obj,count_obj;
String new_count, overdue_count,assigned_count,trash_count,spam_count;
List<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems;
Dialog dialog;
String URL;
Operation op=new Operation();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 

{

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

new getbrand().execute();

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}

getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.folders, frameLayout);
mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
setTitle(listArray[position]);   

folders_list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.folder_display_list);

folders_list.setAdapter(null);
View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.headerview,null);
folders_list.addHeaderView(header, null, false);


if (Operation.isNetworkAvailable(this)) 
{  
new folders().execute();

folders_list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
{

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) 
{
position -= folders_list.getHeaderViewsCount();
String fid = filter_id[position];   
String title=folders[position];
Intent i=new Intent(Folders.this,Tickets.class);
i.putExtra("filter_id","&vis_filter_id="+fid);
i.putExtra("title",title);
i.putExtra("set_queue","no");

startActivity(i);               
}});    
}
else
{
Operation.showToast(getApplicationContext(),R.string.no_network);           
}
}


private class folders extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONArray>
{
Dialog dialog;
@Override
public void onPreExecute() 
{
dialog = new Dialog(Folders.this,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.progressbar);
dialog.show();
}
@Override
protected JSONArray doInBackground(Void... params) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
URL=op.getUrl(getApplicationContext(),"ticket","quick_view","");            
quick_view_array = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(URL+"&vis_encode=json",Folders.this);   
return quick_view_array;
}
@Override
public void onPostExecute(JSONArray quick_view_array) 
{
super.onPostExecute(quick_view_array);
try 
{
quick_view_obj=quick_view_array.getJSONObject(0);
count_obj=quick_view_obj.getJSONObject("count");
folder_count= new ArrayList<String>();
//folder_count.add("");
folder_count.add(count_obj.getString(NEW));
folder_count.add(count_obj.getString(OVERDUE));
folder_count.add(count_obj.getString(ASSIGNED));
folder_count.add(count_obj.getString(TRASH));
folder_count.add(count_obj.getString(SPAM));
folders = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.folders);   
menuItems=new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

for (int i = 0; i <filter_id.length; i++)
{           
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    

map.put(NAME,folders[i]);
map.put(COUNT,folder_count.get(i));
menuItems.add(map);

}


SimpleAdapter list =new SimpleAdapter
(Folders.this, 
menuItems,
R.layout.folders,
new String[] {NAME,COUNT},
new int[] {R.id.folder_name,R.id.folder_count}
)
{    };

folders_list.setAdapter(list);   
dialog.dismiss();
} catch (JSONException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.home, menu); 

SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
.getActionView();
searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

String filter_id = null,Tickets_title = null;
int start_limit=0,page_no=1;

// TODO Auto-generated method stub
switch (item.getItemId())
{     


case R.id.menu_inbox:
Intent inbox = new Intent(Folders.this,Test.class);

startActivity(inbox);
return true;  


default:
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}   
@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{
moveTaskToBack(true);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);       
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
this.finish();
}
private class getbrand extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONArray>
{
Dialog dialog;
@Override
public void onPreExecute() 
{
dialog = new Dialog(Folders.this,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.progressbar);
dialog.show();
}

@Override
protected JSONArray doInBackground(Void... params) 
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
String access=op.getUrl(getApplicationContext(),"ticket","get_branding","");
JSONArray access_denied = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(access+"&vis_encode=json",Folders.this);
return access_denied;

}
@Override
public void onPostExecute(JSONArray access_denied) 
{   
super.onPostExecute(access_denied);
String access_result =access_denied.toString();

ActionBar ab = getActionBar(); 
if(access_result.equals("[\"1\"]"))  
{    ab.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
ab.setIcon(R.drawable.application_icon);


}
else
{
ab.setTitle(R.string.nobrand_app_name);
ab.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ffffff")));

ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.crop1);


ab.setIcon(R.drawable.white3);
}

dialog.dismiss();
}
}

private class getname extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONArray>
{

Dialog dialog;
@Override
public void onPreExecute() 
{
dialog = new Dialog(Folders.this,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.progressbar);
dialog.show();
}

@Override
protected JSONArray doInBackground(Void... params) 
{

String STAFF_URL=op.getUrl(getApplicationContext(),"staff","get_staff_details","");
staff_data_array = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(STAFF_URL+"&vis_encode=json",Folders.this);
return staff_data_array;

}
@Override
public void onPostExecute(JSONArray staff_data_array) 
{   
super.onPostExecute(staff_data_array);
String staff_data_result =staff_data_array.toString();

try {
post_obj = staff_data_array.getJSONObject(0);
String fname=post_obj.getString(FIRST_NAME);
String lname=post_obj.getString(LAST_NAME);
String image=post_obj.getString(PROFILE_IMAGE);

String fullname =fname;

if(fullname=="")
{
fullname="Admin";
}

Fullname="Welcome "+fullname;

TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
tv.setText(Fullname);

tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.default_img,0,0,0);
mDrawerList.addHeaderView(tv, null, false);  

} catch (JSONException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}

dialog.dismiss();
}
}

}
```

Comment: please indent your code, it's not readable well now.

Comment: Please add screenshot of app.

Comment: can you share your xml ?

Comment: @SandeepT Did you checked your response ?.You are adding "Admin" if fullname is empty.Check if there are 2 items without fullname ..

Comment: Check whether your getName AsyncTask is getting called both in your FolderActivity and navigation_drawer_class

Comment: @febi : yes ,I was commented that code in the folder activity...but no effect.

Comment: on line 79 there is a problem, i guess you wanted to assign a value to your `static variable` but there is a local variable which got the value. `position -= mDrawerList.getHeaderViewsCount();`

Comment: @ Sadiq : No it is just to make the title unselectable...........bcoz navdrawer consider the title as a first position.

Comment: @ sunil :No ...such condition.

Comment: @ santosh : I have no rights to upload screenshots on this portal.

Comment: This problem happen only when the app launch and when we click on the navigation drawer icon first time.After selecting any item in the navigation drawer....again click on the nav_drawer_icon then the title shows correct that is single time.